# Can't rename files in the Program Files Directory on Win7

Tags: vb.net, windows-7, file-rename

I am having an issue with my application when tyring to rename files in the Program Files directory.  My application works fine on XP machines, however, on Win7 I get the following error: "Procedure call or argument is not valid."

My code snippet is simple:

```
Rename(Agent_Working_Directory & "\DM_Agent.exe", Agent_Working_Directory & "\DM_Agent.prv")
```

Agent_Working_Directory points to: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Company Name\Application Name"

Basically in a nutshell, I want to be able to rename the old exe file to a .prv so I can auto upgrade my application with a new exe file.

Like I mentioned, the same code works fine on an XP machine with the exact same user credentials.  The local user has full local administrator rights.

Any ideas or comments would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: UAC is enabled, meaning your user doesn't actually have admin rights until elevated, which requires an elevation prompt.  I'm not a VB guy so can't tell you how to do that in VB, but that's what needs to happen.  If it works like C++ etc, a manifest attached to the exe designating it as admin-required will do the job.

Comment: Thanks for the response. As I want the auto update to run in the background without any user intervention, will the manifest allow this?  Or will the user be required to press okay, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Your code works perfectly. You just have to set privileges to Program Files of your account to allow "Modify" as well.

perhaps the following can help you
http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/235732-allow-installed-program-rename-files-under-program-files-x86.html

Comment: There is no need to modify the access permissions on `\Program Files`, doing so is a bad idea in general, and a lot of customers would refuse a program that did something like that.

Comment: Seemed like it would be the easiest solution to his dilemma at the moment. 
If it's okay that I ask, why is it a bad idea? So that Malware can't run on the computer unit to modify Program Files? But doesn't UAC already prevent that?

Comment: Yes, malware is number one but there's also just innocent mistakes by unsophisticated users, or even sophisticated users in a rush.  Allowing write access to a folder like `\Program Files` is opening the gates to the castle to any riff-raff that happens along.  UAC won't stop it since by modifying those folder permissions you've told Windows it doesn't need protecting.  In general, if you think you need to lower protection levels on system resources, you need to re-think your app because your app is broken.